# Dropwizard Jar Stops Running after few Days

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard

I am running Dropwizard jar on a server. Jar runs smoothly for few days after that it stops. I have to redeploy them again and again. I am confused whether it is a jetty error or my code error.

**logs:-**

```
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,682] org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint: changeInterests p=false 0->1 for SelectChannelEndPoint@2bd26a7e{/103.75.33.58:49395<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,1/30000,SslConnection@31c57c5c}{io=0/1,kio=0,kro=1}
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,682] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Queued change SelectChannelEndPoint@2bd26a7e{/103.75.33.58:49395<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,2/30000,SslConnection@31c57c5c}{io=0/1,kio=0,kro=1}:runUpdateKey on org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@34923f7f id=0 keys=4 selected=0
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,682] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector loop woken up from select, 0/4 selected
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,682] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Running change SelectChannelEndPoint@2bd26a7e{/103.75.33.58:49395<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,2/30000,SslConnection@31c57c5c}{io=0/1,kio=0,kro=1}:runUpdateKey
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,682] org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint: Key interests updated 0 -> 1 on SelectChannelEndPoint@2bd26a7e{/103.75.33.58:49395<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,2/30000,SslConnection@31c57c5c}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,682] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector loop waiting on select
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,682] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection: HttpConnection@45813d2[DecryptedEndPoint@182fb3f8{/103.75.33.58:49395<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,3/30000,HttpConnection@45813d2}->SelectChannelEndPoint@2bd26a7e{/103.75.33.58:49395<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,2/30000,SslConnection@31c57c5c}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@5490b545{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@39ed3eb2{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}] onFillable exit HttpChannelState@2096bb19{s=IDLE a=NOT_ASYNC i=true r=!P!U w=false} null
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,683] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection: onFillable exit DecryptedEndPoint@182fb3f8{/103.75.33.58:49395<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,4/30000,HttpConnection@45813d2}->SelectChannelEndPoint@2bd26a7e{/103.75.33.58:49395<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,3/30000,SslConnection@31c57c5c}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,683] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3 ran SelectChannelEndPoint@2bd26a7e{/103.75.33.58:49395<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,3/30000,SslConnection@31c57c5c}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}:runFillable
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,683] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3 produce exit
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:15,683] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: ran EPC Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:35,170] org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout: SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,29533/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout check, elapsed: 29513 ms, remaining: 487 ms
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:35,662] org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout: SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,30025/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout check, elapsed: 30024 ms, remaining: -24 ms
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:35,678] org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout: SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,30025/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout expired
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:35,687] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: close HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:35,688] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: START --> CLOSE
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:35,797] org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection: HttpConnection@566609d2[DecryptedEndPoint@236362d{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,-,-,30059/30000,HttpConnection@566609d2}->SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,-,-,30053/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@52413532{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@72cecda9{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}] onFillInterestedFailed {}
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:35,820] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection: SslConnection@6175e609{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1} -> HttpConnection@566609d2[DecryptedEndPoint@236362d{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,-,-,30178/30000,HttpConnection@566609d2}->SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,-,-,30178/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@52413532{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@72cecda9{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}] shutdownOutput: oshut=false, ishut=false
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:35,856] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection: SslConnection@6175e609{NEED_WRAP,eio=-1/-1,di=-1} -> HttpConnection@566609d2[DecryptedEndPoint@236362d{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,-,-,30219/30000,HttpConnection@566609d2}->SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,-,-,30215/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@52413532{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@72cecda9{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}] flush b[0]=
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:36,091] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection: SslConnection@6175e609{NEED_UNWRAP,eio=-1/69,di=-1} -> HttpConnection@566609d2[DecryptedEndPoint@236362d{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,OSHUT,-,-,30230/30000,HttpConnection@566609d2}->SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,-,-,30226/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=CLOSE,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@52413532{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@72cecda9{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}] wrap Status = CLOSED HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 69
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:36,210] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector loop woken up from select, 1/3 selected
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:36,216] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint: flushed 69 SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,-,-,30579/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:36,217] org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint: onSelected 1->0 r=true w=false for SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,-,-,1/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:36,738] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint: oshut SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,out,-,-,0/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,106] org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint: task SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,OSHUT,-,-,787/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}:runFillable
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,488] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector loop woken up from select, 1/4 selected
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,713] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@2a296f34 produced SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,OSHUT,-,-,1497/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}:runFillable
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,714] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@2a296f34 dispatch
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,714] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: queue EPC Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@2a296f34
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,715] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: run EPC Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@2a296f34
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,715] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@2a296f34 run
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,715] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@2a296f34 produce enter
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,715] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@2a296f34 producing
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,715] org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint: Key interests updated 1 -> 0 on SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,OSHUT,-,-,1499/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,715] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector loop waiting on select
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,715] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@2a296f34 run SelectChannelEndPoint@324c5af{/103.75.33.58:49389<->8443,Open,in,OSHUT,-,-,1499/30000,SslConnection@6175e609}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}:runFillable
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,715] org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest: FillInterest@74419a0e{false,null} fillable null
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,812] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector: Selector loop woken up from select, 2/3 selected
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,902] org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint: onSelected 1->0 r=true w=false for SelectChannelEndPoint@20a688a1{/103.75.33.58:49391<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,29094/30000,SslConnection@43bf0072}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,908] org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint: task SelectChannelEndPoint@20a688a1{/103.75.33.58:49391<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,29094/30000,SslConnection@43bf0072}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}:runFillable
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,911] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3 produced SelectChannelEndPoint@20a688a1{/103.75.33.58:49391<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,29103/30000,SslConnection@43bf0072}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}:runFillable
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,912] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3 dispatch
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,912] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: queue EPC Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,917] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: run EPC Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,917] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3 run
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,917] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3 produce enter
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,917] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3 producing
DEBUG [2017-10-23 07:30:37,919] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume: EPC Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@1c7aefd3 run SelectChannelEndPoint@20a688a1{/103.75.33.58:49391<->8443,Open,in,out,FI,-,29111/30000,SslConnection@43bf0072}{io=0/0,kio=1,kro=1}:runFillable
```

**and yaml configuration**

## Logging settings.

logging:

# The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
 level: DEBUG

appenders:
   - type: console
     threshold: DEBUG
     target: stderr
   - type: file
     threshold: DEBUG
     logFormat: "%-6level [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] %logger{5} - %X{code} %msg %n"
     currentLogFilename: target/application.log
     archive: true
     archivedLogFilenamePattern: target/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz
     archivedFileCount: 7
     timeZone: UTC
swagger:
  schema:
      type: https
  resourcePackage: com.abc.tms.resource

## Server setting

server:
  applicationContextPath: /
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8086
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8984
      # HTTPS Config----
    - type: https
      port: 8943
      keyStorePath: /root/abc/truststore.jks
      keyStorePassword: "abc"
      keyStoreType: jks
      validateCerts: false
      validatePeers: false

```
  bindHost: 0.0.0.0 # only bind to loopback
  headerCacheSize: 512 bytes
  outputBufferSize: 32KiB
  maxRequestHeaderSize: 8KiB
  maxResponseHeaderSize: 8KiB
  inputBufferSize: 8KiB
  idleTimeout: 30 seconds
  minBufferPoolSize: 64 bytes
  bufferPoolIncrement: 1KiB
  maxBufferPoolSize: 64KiB
  acceptorThreads: 1
  selectorThreads: 2
  acceptQueueSize: 1024
  reuseAddress: true
  soLingerTime: 345s
  useServerHeader: false
  useDateHeader: true
  useForwardedHeaders: true
```

I have checked server free ram free -ht:-
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           992M        766M         87M         10M        137M         57M
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
Total:         992M        766M         87M

**JVM Heap size :-**
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 
'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0          
                         {pd product}
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0         
                         {product}
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520   
                       {product}
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 16777216   
                      {product}
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728    
                     {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 262144000    
                     {product}
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024         
                      {pd product}
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024          
                     {pd product}

Comment: I am  also getting same issues and read some articals online according to that, Jetty server get hangs abd throws exceptions and Dropwizard doesn't have control on it. Need to do more R&D on jetty servers.